# View users login activity

Tags: windows-7, event-log

Is there a way from the local event logs of a windows 7 computer to tell when the users logged into the cpu?-

I see logon 4624 / logoff  4634

But those seem to be every 30min or so not tied to users actually sitting at the computer

Comment: 4624 is a logon event, but will include every type of logon that happens on the system. Filter by TargetUserName and LogonType to get the details you want - or let us know what type of logons you want to view (specifically) and we'll show you how.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run scripts on the event viewer - either you can create your own or use one of the free scripts out there like [WinLogOnView](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/windows_log_on_times_view.html)

Your own script would look something like this:

```
@echo off
if not exist c:\Logs md c:\Logs
echo Logon: %date% %time:~0,5% %UserName% >> c:\Logs\History.txt
```

Comment: My question is not how to view I can download into excel. Its what am I looking for that will accurately tell me when the user was logging into the machine. In the current log from 10/4/14 to today there are roughly 9,000,000 logon events and 7,000,000 logoff events so clearly thats not what i think it is

Comment: I find it's easier to work with the logs when exported - for example in Excel you can easily filter based on the username that you want to see logon and logoff. I think that would get you what you are after. Otherwise you can search for the username in the eventviewer - much harder